# SQL Issue querying database between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following records in the DB below is the created date for each record.

2013-11-09 12:55:43.000
2013-10-29 19:01:53.000
2013-10-29 04:59:42.000

My SQL query looks like this

```
Select d.Name as DealerName, Sum(c.CommissionAmount) as CommissionAmount
from Dealer d
Left join Commission c on c.Dealerid = d.DealerId
where c.CreatedDate between isnull(@FromDate, c.CreatedDate) and isnull(@ToDate, c.CreatedDate)
Group by d.Name
Order by CommissionAmount desc
```

When I enter the following dates in to my search functionality

From date = 29/10/2013
To date = 09/11/2013

It only returns one record, when it should return three, yet if I leave From date as it is and pass in null for To date I get two records back

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

When You are using `Dates` in `where` clause Always use Same casting on both sides

```
Select d.Name as DealerName, Sum(c.CommissionAmount) as CommissionAmount
from Dealer d
Left join Commission c on c.Dealerid = d.DealerId
where CAST(c.CreatedDate as DATE) between 
CAST(isnull(@FromDate, c.CreatedDate) as DATE) and 
CAST(isnull(@ToDate, c.CreatedDate) as DATE)
Group by d.Name
Order by CommissionAmount desc
```

Comment: I have tried yours 

declare fromdate datetime ='29/10/2013'
,todate datetime ='09/11/2013'

Select d.Name as DealerName, Sum(c.CommissionAmount) as CommissionAmount
from Dealer d
Left join Commission c on c.Dealerid = d.DealerId
where CAST(c.CreatedDate as DATE) between 
CAST(isnull(FromDate, c.CreatedDate) as DATE) and 
CAST(isnull(ToDate, c.CreatedDate) as DATE)
Group by d.Name
Order by CommissionAmount desc   

but I get the following error 
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. have to remove "@" from variables

Answer (score 0):

The problem is u have defined the variables without time So the `@todate` will be like `'2013-11-09 00:00:00.000'`.

But in the table date has time. Between operator will not consider this date `'2013-11-09 12:55:43.000'` since it is higher than the todate u have mentioned thats y you are getting two rows.

so try this.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
  (dates DATETIME)

INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES     ('2013-11-09 12:55:43.000'),
            ('2013-10-29 19:01:53.000'),
            ('2013-10-29 04:59:42.000')


DECLARE @from VARCHAR(50)='29/10/2013',
        @to   VARCHAR(50) ='09/11/2013'

SELECT *
FROM   #temp
WHERE  (@from is not null and @to is not null and Cast(dates AS DATE) BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE, @from, 103) AND CONVERT(DATE, @to, 103) ) or 1=1
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/78fd1/2)**

Comment: I still don't get the three rows, I'm passing in dd/mm/yyyy not dd-mm-yyyy as 09/11/2013 00:00:00 and 29/10/2013 00:00:00

Comment: As I pass in dd/mm/yyyy and your example shows it in a format of yyyy-mm-dd I need to change the format of my values going in to match yours how can I do that?

Comment: how do I cater for the null value for from and to date? I tried modifying the fiddle you wrote but I get an exception as on page load I pass in nulls, then when the user searches I pass in the values

Comment: What did u try can u post that in question with null data

Comment: SELECT *
FROM   #temp
WHERE  Cast(dates AS DATE) BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE, Isnull(@from, dates), 103) AND CONVERT(DATE, Isnull(@to, dates), 103) @Pradeep

Comment: If from or to is null means you want to replace with what value?

Comment: If they are null I want to return everything, only when they search should I filter the results @Pradeep

Comment: that works, but is there a way I can change the format from dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd to make it simpler? So when the user enters 29/10/2013 I can pass I  2013-10-29

Comment: @ScottAtkinson That is what we have done here `CONVERT(DATE, @from, 103)` this will convert this format `29/10/2013` to `2013-10-29`

Comment: what is 1=1 is the query doing? sorry my SQL skills are limited, a dba would be doing this week but he is away for the next two weeks.

Comment: @ScottAtkinson It will return all the rows from the table because condition is satisfied. Try this. `select * from <anytable> where 1=1` this will return all the rows in that table.

Comment: thanks I see it working but what is the correct way to handle dates from a web application point of view, I have a class called Filter which consist of two datetimes "FromDate" and "ToDate" which gets passed to the view and the user can enter a date, the example you have given me is using varchars, so am I write in saying I should change the filter class from datetimes to strings?

Comment: @ScottAtkinson - Always try to send the date in this format `2013-10-29` from UI so that we don't have to do any conversions and also u can declare the `from` and `to` with `datetime datatype`

Comment: if the user types in 29/09/2013 for example how do I change that format to 2013-09-29 before passing to the server? The code is working but I have made fromdate and todate strings

Answer (score 0):

You can do  this by using tow ways one is

**1. CAST**

```
 CAST(c.CreatedDate as DATE)
```

**2. `CONVERT`**

```
CONVERT(varchar(10), c.CreatedDate)
```

Here is the both the ways that you can achieve.

```
1.  where 
    CONVERT(varchar(10), c.CreatedDate)
    between 
    isnull(@FromDate, c.CreatedDate) 
    and 
    isnull(@ToDate, c.CreatedDate)


 2. where 
    CAST(c.CreatedDate as DATE)
    between 
    isnull(@FromDate, c.CreatedDate) 
    and 
    isnull(@ToDate, c.CreatedDate)
```

Difference between cast & convert is You can Apply any style format you need in the `CONVERT` function .There are many date time format availabe for `CONVErT` function [Refer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187928.aspx) this link You will get all the styple format in the SQL.

Syntax for the COnvert is

```
CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression [ , style ] )
```

where `expression [ , style ]` is optional field.

**CAST** :

Cast is available after the version of SQL 2005. cast also Converts an expression of one data type to another in SQL Server.
**Syntax**

```
CAST ( expression AS data_type [ ( length ) ] )
```

`[ ( length ) ]` is optional field in Cast

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
    SELECT      d.Name as DealerName, Sum(c.CommissionAmount) as CommissionAmount
    FROM        Dealer d
    LEFT JOIN   Commission c on c.Dealerid = d.DealerId
    WHERE       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CAST(c.CreatedDate AS DATE),103) 
                BETWEEN isnull(@FromDate, c.CreatedDate) and isnull(@ToDate, c.CreatedDate)
    Group by    d.Name
    Order by    CommissionAmount desc
```